# constexpr and templates error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I have next code which compiles fine on Visual Studio 2015:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        constexpr Base(float value);

    private:
        float    _value;
};

constexpr Base::Base(float value)
    : _value(value)
{
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        constexpr Derived(float value)
            : Base(value)
        {
        }
};
```

By changing it to:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    protected:
        constexpr Base(T value);

    private:
        T    _value;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr Base<T>::Base(T value)
    : _value(value)
{
}

class Derived : public Base<float>
{
    public:
        constexpr Derived(float value)
            : Base(value)
        {
        }
};
```

I get following error:

> error C2134: 'Base< float >::Base': call does not result in a constant expression
>
> note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
>
> note: see declaration of 'Base< float >::Base'

By implementing `Base`'s constructor inside the class the error magically disappears:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    protected:
        constexpr Base(T value)
            : _value(value)
        {
        }

    private:
        T    _value;
};

class Derived : public Base<float>
{
    public:
        constexpr Derived(float value)
            : Base(value)
        {
        }
};
```

Is this a bug in the compiler or I'm doing something wrong in the second case?

EDIT: All 3 versions compile fine with clang and gcc

Answer (score 0):

> A note about C++11 constexpr: this is a large feature with complicated
>   interactions throughout the Core Language, implemented in a compiler
>   codebase undergoing modernization, being shipped for the first time. 
>   It contains bugs/limitations, some of which you might notice, and many
>   of which will be fixed in Updates.  (For example, the compiler is
>   currently unable to emit initializers for non-scalar static constexpr
>   data members, including character arrays.  This scenario has been
>   blocked with a warning-as-error C4579.)  Nevertheless, I've chosen to
>   list the compiler's support for C++11 constexpr as being complete,
>   because the STL is successfully using it, and quite intensively so. 
>   (The STL's handful of missing constexpr occurrences are due to
>   library-only issues, the absence of magic compiler hooks, and the
>   absence of C++14 extended constexpr loops.)

From here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx

It is probably not yet supported.